# How can I get the contents of my GUI to look a certain way? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

So, I'm brand spankin' new to programming, so thanks in advance for your help. I'm trying to put this base 2 to base 10/base 10 to base 2 calculator I have made into a GUI. For the life of me I can't figure out how to nicely format it. I'm trying to make it look like the following: The two radio buttons on top, the input textfield bellow those, the convert button bellow that, the output field bellow that, and the clear button bellow that. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

   private JTextField input;
   private JTextField output;
   private JRadioButton base2Button;
   private JRadioButton base10Button;
   private JButton convert;
   private JButton clear;
   private Container canvas = getContentPane();
   private Color GRAY;

       public GUI()

      {

     this.setTitle("Base 10-2 calc");
     this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
     //this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
      base2Button = new JRadioButton( "Convert to base 2");   
      base10Button = new JRadioButton( "Convert to base 10"); 

      ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      radioGroup.add(base2Button);
      radioGroup.add(base10Button);

      JPanel radioButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
      radioButtonsPanel.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );

      radioButtonsPanel.add(base2Button);
      radioButtonsPanel.add(base10Button);

      canvas.add(radioButtonsPanel);

      base2Button.setSelected( true );
      base10Button.setSelected( true );

      input = new JTextField(18);
      //input = new JFormattedTextField(20);
      canvas.add(input);
      output = new JTextField(18);
      //output = new JFormattedTextField(20);
      canvas.add(output);

      convert = new JButton("Convert!");
      convert.addActionListener(this);
      canvas.add(convert);

      clear = new JButton("Clear");
      clear.addActionListener(this);
      canvas.add(clear); 

      output.setBackground(GRAY);
      output.setEditable(false);

      this.setSize(300, 200);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setLocation(99, 101);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        GUI app = new GUI();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        String s = e.getActionCommand();

        if(s.equals("Convert!"))
        {
            String numS = input.getText();
            int numI = Integer.parseInt(numS);

            if(base2Button.isSelected())
            {
              output.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(numI)));
            }

            if(base10Button.isSelected())
            {
              output.setText("" + Integer.valueOf(numS,2));
            }
         }    

         if(s.equals("Clear"))
         {
             input.setText("");
             output.setText("");
         }


     }

}
```

Comment: Read the layout manager tutorials, and then use the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing). Remember that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout, in order to create complex and easy to maintain GUI's.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple layout, you could use a GridLayout with one column and then use a bunch of child panels with FlowLayout which align the components based on the available space in a single row. If you want more control, I'd suggest learning about the GridBagLayout manager which is a more flexible version of GridLayout.

```
public class ExampleGUI {

    public ExampleGUI() {
        init();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        // Set the frame's layout to a GridLayout with one column
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // Child panels, each with FlowLayout(), which aligns the components
        // in a single row, until there's no more space
        JPanel radioButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("Option 1");
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Option 2");
        radioButtonPanel.add(button1);
        radioButtonPanel.add(button2);
        
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Input: ");
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(15);
        inputPanel.add(inputLabel);
        inputPanel.add(textField1);
        
        JPanel convertPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
        convertPanel.add(convertButton);
        
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Output: ");
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(15);
        outputPanel.add(outputLabel);
        outputPanel.add(textField2);
        
        // Add the child panels to the frame, in order, which all get placed
        // in a single column
        frame.add(radioButtonPanel);
        frame.add(inputPanel);
        frame.add(convertPanel);
        frame.add(outputPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleGUI example = new ExampleGUI();
    }

}
```

The end result:

[image]